# Plot a third value with respect to the first two

Tags: r, plot, machine-learning

I have the following data:

```
kNN,               kMeans,           expected
1.1048387096774193,2.019927536231884,0.0
1.521505376344086,2.0120481927710845,0.0
1.271505376344086,2.019927536231884,0.0
2.020833333333333,2.019927536231884,0.0
0.7708333333333334,2.019927536231884,0.0
4.020408163265306,2.0120481927710845,0.0
0.6210526315789474,2.019927536231884,0.0
0.7708333333333334,2.019927536231884,0.0
3.354166666666667,2.019927536231884,0.0
2.020833333333333,2.019927536231884,1.0
1.450310559006211,2.0120481927710845,0.0
0.8719780219780221,2.019927536231884,-1.0
4.020408163265306,2.019927536231884,-1.0
3.520618556701031,2.019927536231884,1.0
1.521505376344086,2.019927536231884,0.0
```

I want to plot the `expected` with respect to the values in `kNN` and `kMeans`? I tried scatter plot read about plotting in R, but cannot decide which plot is useful. Any help would be appreciated. I tried scatter plot but it did not give me much information

My aim here is to explore the data to see if I can train single layer perception to arrive close to the expected. If the data is linearly separable (multi-class hence one against rest method).

Thanks.

Comment: It's going to be a strange plot if all those 'expected's are {-1,0,1}. You should decide what you want to show...first, then pose the question.

Comment: @DWin I am not sure, if I understand when you say I should decide what I want to show. I want to explore this data and want to plot these three outputs with respect to the two other values in the row.
I am happy if I can show an 'X' of -1, 'O' for 0 and 'D' for 1, I want to know if there is any type of graph that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i could come up with:

```
dat <-
structure(list(kNN = c(1.10483870967742, 1.52150537634409, 1.27150537634409, 
2.02083333333333, 0.770833333333333, 4.02040816326531, 0.621052631578947, 
0.770833333333333, 3.35416666666667, 2.02083333333333, 1.45031055900621, 
0.871978021978022, 4.02040816326531, 3.52061855670103, 1.52150537634409
), kMeans = c(2.01992753623188, 2.01204819277108, 2.01992753623188, 
2.01992753623188, 2.01992753623188, 2.01204819277108, 2.01992753623188, 
2.01992753623188, 2.01992753623188, 2.01992753623188, 2.01204819277108, 
2.01992753623188, 2.01992753623188, 2.01992753623188, 2.01992753623188
), expected = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0
)), .Names = c("kNN", "kMeans", "expected"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

plot(dat$kNN, dat$kMeans, col=dat$expected+2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `kMeans` only has two values try this:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(expected ~ kNN | kMeans, DF, pch = 20, col = 1)
```

The left panel shows the data for `kMeans=2.012` and the right for `kMeans=2.019`.  In the `kMeans=2.012` case all `expected` values are 0; however, we only have three points so that is not based on much.  In the `kMeans=2.019` case there does not appear to be a relationship between `kNN` and `expected`.

[image]